# Store in Cosmos data coming from Orion to Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I have one doubt about how to persist data in an architecture where Cygnus is subscribed to Orion Context Broker and then Cygnus must persist data in Cosmos. Is it necessary to implement a custom WebHDFS client for persisting the data from Cygnus to Cosmos or can it be automatically stored if we configure Cosmos via CLI? After reading some documentation I don't know if this "last step" can be done through configuration using CLI or if a custom client is needed. When could be not necessary a custom WebHDFS client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, Cygnus subscribes to Orion in order to receive notifications about certain desired entities, when any of their attributes changes.

What happens then? Cygnus uses WebHDFS REST API for writting data into Cosmos HDFS, typically a file per notified entity. Initially, if the file does not exits, the "create" operation from the REST API is used; if it already exists, the "append" operation is used.

Where are the above files created? Cygnus HDFS files path is as:

```
/user/<your_cosmos_username>/<notified_fiware_service>/<notified_fiware_servicePath>/<built_destination>/<built_destination>.txt
```

The `notified_fiware_service` and `notified_fiware_servicePath` are Http headers sent by Orion in the notification; they are about how to organize the data. The `built_destination` is usually the result of concatenating the notified `entityId` and the `entityType`.

Finally, `your_cosmos_username` is your Linux and HDFS username in the FIWARE LAB Cosmos deployment. This is obtained by login with your FIWARE LAB credentials at http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org/cosmos-gui/. You only have to this once in your life; it is, let's say, a provisioning step that creates the Unix username and your HDFS userspace.

Comment: Thank you very much! So as you said, I will only do the "provisioning step" without programming any specific CLI.